# uploading picture from php form into oracle database

Tags: php, image, oracle, uploading, oracle11gr2

I have a problem in uploading an image to oracle database .

this is my database.php 
it takes the values from a form and send it to my database .
my oracle version is 11g .

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ar-sa">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<?php
session_start();
    include('connection.php');
    /* @var $fname type */
     $fname=$_POST["fname"];
     $sn=$_POST["sn"];
     $gender=$_POST["gender"];
     $email=$_POST["email"];
     $passwd=$_POST["passwd"];
     $unvi=$_POST["unvi"];
     $section=$_POST["section"];
     $dep=$_POST["dep"];
     $phone=$_POST["phone"];
     $tren=$_POST["tren"];
     $hour=$_POST["hour"];
     $period=$_POST["period"];
     $term=$_POST["term"];
     $year=$_POST["year"];


 $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png","JPG");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/JPG")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {


    if (file_exists("student/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "student/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);


            $pic= "student/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

$insert ="INSERT INTO APPLICATION(NAME,SN,GENDER,PASS,UNVI,DEP,PHONE,TERM,HOUR,PERIOD,TREN,YEAR,EMAIL,SECTION,STATE,PIC)VALUES(:fname,:sn, :gender, :passwd, :unvi, :dep, :phone, :term, :hour, :period, :tren, :year,:email,:section,'Waiting',:pic)";
  $send = oci_parse($conn, $insert);

oci_bind_by_name($send, ':fname', $fname);
oci_bind_by_name($send, ':sn', $sn);
oci_bind_by_name($send, ':gender', $gender);
 oci_bind_by_name($send, ':passwd', $passwd);
 oci_bind_by_name($send, ':unvi', $unvi);
  oci_bind_by_name($send, ':section', $section);
 oci_bind_by_name($send, ':dep', $dep);
 oci_bind_by_name($send, ':phone', $phone);
 oci_bind_by_name($send, ':term', $term);
 oci_bind_by_name($send, ':hour', $hour);
 oci_bind_by_name($send, ':period', $period);
 oci_bind_by_name($send, ':tren', $tren);
 oci_bind_by_name($send, ':year', $year);

 oci_bind_by_name($send, ':email', $email);
 oci_bind_by_name($send, ':pic', $pic);

 oci_execute($send,OCI_DEFAULT);

header("location:requestm.php");




?>
```

//////////////////////////////

my database table is

```
CREATE TABLE  "APPLICATION" 
   (    "NAME" NVARCHAR2(100), 
    "SN" VARCHAR2(300), 
    "GENDER" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "PASS" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "UNVI" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "DEP" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "PHONE" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "TERM" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "HOUR" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "PERIOD" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "TREN" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "YEAR" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SECTION" VARCHAR2(200), 
    "STATE" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "PIC" VARCHAR2(3000), 
    "NOTE" VARCHAR2(1000), 
     CONSTRAINT "APPLICATION_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("SN") ENABLE
   ) ;
```

the PIC column i want it to store the path of the picture .
please help

Answer (score 0):

the pic should be a BLOB. Here is doc about it [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefblob.html) and with example about storing pictures.

and by the way, your varchar2 wouldn't be working anyway. In php you have the max size of a pic 2MB but the column has 3K characters.